# A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations in push servlet

Tags: primefaces, websocket, atmosphere

We have an issue when we are trying to implement the use servlet with the help of  atmosphere dependency
We can run in locally with current configuration but when my appliction is deployed  to aws then push servlet not working.
the logs in aws is
My Aws server configration is Java 8 with Tomcat 8 version 2.1.3

64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Tomcat 8 Java 8
2016.03.2
Java 1.8.0_91
Tomcat 8.0.35
Apache 2.2.31

```
05-Dec-2017 13:26:32.162 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Push Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1621)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1037)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:398)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.startAsync(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:631)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:95)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:70)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2287)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:177)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We are using the Primeface 
Primeface  dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

atmosphere dependency

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
  <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.6</version> 
</dependency>
```

Push servlet configration in web.xml is

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Cross posted: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/2304

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was fixed. Its cause by my mistaken
When I check through all of the filters I found another filter element `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` that filter works for when push servlet calls.

Comment: What changes did fix the issue?

Comment: <async-supported>true</async-supported>

Answer (score 2):

Changing  to false

webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ApplicationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.chomp.blurp.ApplicationFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ApplicationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```